# Check if there is a label inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to check if there is a label inside the `li` with find children but I'm newbie and can't do it right I know it's easy but I'm new in Jquery :

**HTML :**

```
<li class="dropdown open">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">
        Something
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="test" type="checkbox" value="Test" class="checkbox">
            <label for="test">Test</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the `length` :

```
if( $('li').find('label').length )
    //exist
else
    //does not exist
```

Hope this helps.

```js
if( $('li').find('label').length )
  console.log('Label exist');
else
  console.log('Label does not exist');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown open">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">
        Something
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="test" type="checkbox" value="Test" class="checkbox">
            <label for="test">Test</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to count the number of `label` present in `li`

```
$("li").find("label[for='test']").length
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft added . thnks

Answer (score 0):

There you are:

```
if($('li').find('label').length{
    // there is a label
}else{
   // no label here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length with dom traversing for this:

```
if($('li').find('label').length)
{
   // code here
}
else
{
   // code here
}
```